# Kill a java process in windows programmatically

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar

I have many executable jar files which I am running in a windows server. Sometime, I need to redeploy some of the applications. For that, I need to first stop the existing process and then start the new process. 
In linux environment I am using `pkill` to kill the process based on the jar file name. But in windows, all the java processes will be named as "java.exe" only. I need to write a batch file to do this start and stop operations. 
How can I kill the jar file based on the name.

Assume that my jar file is named as `common-api.jar`. 
Running the command `jps -ml | find "common"` would give the result as

> 6968 common-api.jar

I can kill the process by `taskkill /f /PID 6968`

But How can I extract the process id from the first command and pass it to the `taskkill` command ?

Comment: If you're *killing processes* instead of shutting down services, you're doing it wrong. Make your program conform to the usual service architecture on both platforms. Then you can use normal OS commands for stopping and starting services.

Comment: You can do it by a vbscript with Win32_Process list in WMI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('jps -ml ^| find /i "common"') do set PID=%%a
taskkill /f /PID %PID%
```

or from command prompt:

```
for /f "delims= " %a in ('jps -ml ^| find /i "common"') do set PID=%a
```

Comment: It is giving error as "%%a was unexpected at this time."

Comment: are you using this form batch file or from commnd prompt?

Answer (score 1):

In vbscript we can do something like that just give a try with it :

```
Option Explicit
Call KillProcessbyName("common-api.jar")
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub KillProcessbyName(FileName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WshShell,strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,objProcess
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        If InStr(objProcess.CommandLine,FileName) > 0 Then
            If Err <> 0 Then
                MsgBox Err.Description,VbCritical,Err.Description
            Else
                objProcess.Terminate(0) 
            End if
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('jps -ml ^| find "common"') do (taskkill /F /PID %%A )
```